# Upload image from android gallery to Firebase storage using HttpPost

Tags: android, upload, http-post, firebase-storage

I create an android application that uploads an image from a gallery to Firebase storage, I need to use HttpPost to upload the image.

My code is as the following:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent 
data) {
switch (requestCode) {
case TAKE_AVATAR_GALLERY_REQUEST:
if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
Uri photoUri = data.getData();
Bitmap avatar= Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), photoUri);
String strAvatarFilename = "avatar.jpg";
try {
 avatar.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100,
 openFileOutput(strAvatarFilename, MODE_PRIVATE));
} catch (Exception e) {
Log.e(DEBUG_TAG, "Avatar compression and save failed.", e);
}

Uri imageUriToSaveCameraImageTo = Uri.fromFile(new File(
QuizSettingsActivity.this.getFilesDir(), strAvatarFilename));
Editor editor = mGameSettings.edit();
editor.putString(GAME_PREFERENCES_AVATAR, 
imageUriToSaveCameraImageTo.getPath());
editor.commit();
```

In the doInBackground method I call postAvatarToServer which is as following :

```
private boolean postAvatarToServer() {
    boolean succeeded = false;
    String avatar = mGameSettings.getString(GAME_PREFERENCES_AVATAR, "");
    MultipartEntity entity = new 
           MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
    File file = new File(avatar);
    if (file.exists()) {
        FileBody encFile = new FileBody(file);
        entity.addPart("avatar", encFile);
        HttpPost request = new 
            HttpPost("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/HERE I 
            WRITE THE FOLDER URL WITHOUT [gs://]/o/");
        request.setEntity(entity);
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        try {
             HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
             HttpEntity r_entity = response.getEntity();
            int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            String responseString = null;
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                    responseString = EntityUtils.toString(r_entity);
            } else {
                    responseString = "Error occurred! Http Status Code: "
                                + statusCode;
            }
            succeeded = true;

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
           Log.e(DEBUG_TAG, "Unexpected ClientProtocolException",e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(DEBUG_TAG, "Unexpected IOException", e);
        }
} else {
    Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "No avatar to upload");
    succeeded = true;
            }
    return succeeded;

        }
```

In the logcat I get !Error occurred! Http Status Code: 400

So where is the error and how to solve it ...

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [the existing Android SDK](http://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files)?

```
Uri file = Uri.fromFile(new File("path/to/local/file.jpg"));
StorageReference storageRef = storageRef.child("images/"+file.getLastPathSegment());
uploadTask = storageRef.putFile(file);
```

Comment: Yes, I know that I can use it. I try it and its work but I have to do the upload using HttpPost. My code is for proving that using HttpPost can upload image to Firebase